# Handling Errors in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have written a service that fetches data from my server in the following fashion:

```js
myApp.factory('CommonHttpService', function($http, $q){
var myUrl;

return{
    query: function(tableName){ 
    //Forming the URl
    myUrl = baseUrl + "?table=" + tableName;

    // Create a deferred object
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //Calling web api to fetch all rows from table
    $http.get(myUrl).success(function(data){            
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(){
        // Sending a friendly error message in case of failure
        deferred.reject("An Error occured while fetching items");
    });

    // Returning the promise object
    return deferred.promise;


}});
```

My Controller calls it like this:

```js
 // Get entire list
CommonHttpService.query(tableName).then(function(data) { 
   $scope.list = data;                            
});
```

So my question is, in this entire scheme of things I am not sure HOW or WHERE to handle errors.
Does the error get handled in deferred.reject().. if so how ?

Or does it get handled after the .then() in the controller.

Ideally I should be displaying some sort of message to the user like "No data found" and itnernally sending the error details to the admin or something

Those who have done, this before and have any bits of advice kindly pass them ON.

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then expects two function first is sucess and second is failure

```js
 CommonHttpService.query(tableName).then(function(data) { 
       $scope.list = data;                            
    },function(error){
    alert("error")
    }); 

You should directly return $http.get which also returns a promise 
--Refactoring --- 
       myApp.factory('CommonHttpService', function($http, $q){
    var myUrl;
    return{
        query: function(tableName){ 

        myUrl = baseUrl + "?table=" + tableName;
        //$http.get also returns a promise 
        return $http.get(myUrl)

    }});

        CommonHttpService.query(tableName).then(function(data) { 
       $scope.list = data;                            
    },function(error){alert(error});
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay .. what purpose does deferred.reject() serve in the whole equation above

Comment: deffered.reject means your promise has been rejected which means promise has returned a error so the error function of then() will be executed if you do deffered.resolve which means promise has been sucessfully resolved and the sucess function code will be executed

Comment: so the error(function(){.. } in http.get is also executed and the error function after then() is also executed.
What is the whole purpose of having two functions execute upon error ?

Comment: I have refactored the code and am directly returning http.get() .. this way there is only one place to handle the error which is my controller. Thanks for your input